# Where is Gendry?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

I keep thinking something is missing in Game of Thrones, and I just realized what it is: where the heck is Gendry? The last thing I heard he was rowing off after narrowly escaping being one of the Red Queen's human sacrifices:

[image]

Well, where is he? Rowing to America? Eaten by a whale? Doing a Daenerys Targaryen and "gathering his forces"?

Comment: His return in S7 shows he must be the most athletically fit person in Westeros. Not only rowing great distances, but an incredible cross-country runner